# HTTPS Address Bar Styling

Tags: css

Does anybody know how to implement the additional appearance on the address bar when using HTTPS. Example:

[Nationwide Example Link Here](https://onlinebanking.nationwide.co.uk/AccessManagement/Login)!

Instead of just showing a padlock, Nationwide also shows: Nationwide Building Society [GB]

Which I think looks cool, but I have no idea how to do something similar. I'm assuming this is CSS but I could be way off the mark.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: it has to do with the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot style it with CSS.

Wikipedia has a few nice articles about this, including the "styling".

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_validation_certificate

What you want is an extended validation certificate, but it will cost you some money to get one through a trusted provider or "Certificate Authority" such as Comodo.

A google search will show you some providers. https://www.google.com/search?q=SSL+extended+validation+certificate

They often cost well over $100 per year for a basic one.

Answer (score 5):

CSS can't control the address bar. Some browsers choose to add the name of the company that the SSL certificate verifies.

Answer (score 2):

That shows up for **verified** sites that have an SSL certificate.

It's important to note that something like that only shows up when the page connection is encrypted.  At http://github.com for example, it has a warning symbol because:

> Your connection to github.com is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure.

All these need to be configured in order for that to show up.

also as @Mooseman says, CSS does not control that.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not CSS. Has to do with the type/setup of the SSL certificate. Basically it's an additional verification that the person who requested/purchased the SSL Cert. is who they claim to be. It's called "Extended Validation" and most modern browsers will support it.

To contrast with a "normal" SSL certificate, which simply confirms that the data between the host and browser is encrypted.

http://www.thawte.com/resources/getting-started/extended-validation-ssl-faq/